# Merging two dataframes based on timestamp column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to combine two Pandas dataframes together where they both have a timestamp column with some of the same timestamp values, some different, and several other different columns. Because the only column these dataframes share is the timestamp column, how I want to combine them is such that if there's a matching timestamp value, then I just want to merge the columns together for that row. If the timestamp is different, then I still want to merge columns together, but add in NaNs in the columns of the dataframe that didn't have that timestamp. Please check out the sample code below for a clearer explanation:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

gt = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.array([1.5, 2, 3]),
    'gt_x':np.array([50, 55, 57.5]),
    'gt_y':np.array([60, 65, 67.5]),
    'gt_z':np.array([70, 75, 77.5])})

svo = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.array([1.5, 2.5, 3.5]),
    'svo_x':np.array([11.1, 7.4, 15.7]),
    'svo_y':np.array([13.2, 34.5, 32.8]),
    'svo_z':np.array([17.3, 23.6, 19.9])})

i_want_this_after_merge = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.array([1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5]),
    'gt_x':np.array([50, 55, np.nan, 57.5, np.nan]),
    'gt_y':np.array([60, 65, np.nan, 67.5, np.nan]),
    'gt_z':np.array([70, 75, np.nan, 77.5, np.nan]),
    'svo_x':np.array([11.1, np.nan, 7.4, np.nan, 15.7]),
    'svo_y':np.array([13.2, np.nan, 34.5, np.nan, 32.8]),
    'svo_z':np.array([17.3, np.nan, 23.6, np.nan, 19.9])})
```

In case you're unable to run the code, this is what the dataframes in the above code sample look like:

**gt:**

```
   time  gt_x  gt_y  gt_z
0   1.5  50.0  60.0  70.0
1   2.0  55.0  65.0  75.0
2   3.0  57.5  67.5  77.5
```

**svo:**

```
   time  svo_x  svo_y  svo_z
0   1.5   11.1   13.2   17.3
1   2.5    7.4   34.5   23.6
2   3.5   15.7   32.8   19.9
```

And after merging these two, this is the output I'm looking for:

```
   time  gt_x  gt_y  gt_z  svo_x  svo_y  svo_z
0   1.5  50.0  60.0  70.0   11.1   13.2   17.3
1   2.0  55.0  65.0  75.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
2   2.5   NaN   NaN   NaN    7.4   34.5   23.6
3   3.0  57.5  67.5  77.5    NaN    NaN    NaN
4   3.5   NaN   NaN   NaN   15.7   32.8   19.9
```

I've gone through several posts seemingly related to this question, and tried things such as using the pandas merge function with various join conditions, such as "inner". I've also tried pandas.merge_asof, but that hasn't accomplished what I wanted either. Would anyone have any ideas what I could do here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `gt.merge(svo, on='time', how='outer').sort_values('time')`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!